# Why same array is being repeated everytime?

Tags: javascript

I am a react developer, there is some task need to be done in vanilla JS, I dont know whats I am doing wrong over here.

This is a simple select

```
 <select id="js-year-selected" onchange="getYear()" class="js-year-input">
                <option value="2020">2020</option>
                <option value="2019" >2019</option>
                <option value="2018">2018</option>
                <option value="2017">2017</option>
                <option value="2016" >2016</option>
                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                <option value="2014">2014</option>
</select>
```

This is the onchange fucntion:-

```
function getYear() {
  var getYear = document.getElementById("js-year-selected");
  var strUser = getYear.options[getYear.selectedIndex].value;
  var getJSON = document.getElementById("json-input").innerHTML;

  data = JSON.parse(getJSON);
  var year = strUser;
  console.log(year);

  let filterDataUtil = data.filter(function(dataItem) {
    return dataItem.birthday.split("/")[2].localeCompare(strUser) !== -1;
  });
  console.log(filterDataUtil)
}
```

And whatever year i put it's only returning the value of year 2020 and appending new values to it.

Sample JSON

```
<textarea class="app__txt js-json" id="json-input" placeholder="Paste the json here.">[
    {
      "name": "Tyrion Lannister",
      "birthday": "12/02/2020"
    }, {
      "name": "Cersei Lannister",
      "birthday": "11/30/1975"
    }, {
      "name": "Daenerys Targaryen",
      "birthday": "11/24/1991"
    }, {
      "name": "Arya Stark",
      "birthday": "11/25/2020"
    }, {
      "name": "Jon Snow",
      "birthday": "12/03/1989"
    }, {
      "name": "Sansa Stark",
      "birthday": "08/15/1992"
    }, {
      "name": "Jorah Mormont",
      "birthday": "12/16/1968"
    }
]</textarea>
```

Comment: What is `document.getElementById("json-input")`?

Comment: JSON file getting from a innerText, pasted somewhere

Comment: I cant, open up more code.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? All the years in your `<select>` are less than or equal `2020` and greater than `1992` (the latest year in your array other than 2020).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `localeCompare` wrong - it returns `0` when the strings are equal, or a negative / positive number depending on how the two strings compare.

In this case, you just have two strings containing years, so just use `===` to compare them.

Comment: Oh god, I was going around scoping and all for an hour.

Comment: Sometimes all it takes is another pair of eyes :)

Comment: True, absolutely.

Answer (score 2):

Simple comparsion is required

```
dataItem.birthday.split("/")[2] === strUser;
```

```js
function getYear() {
  var getYear = document.getElementById("js-year-selected");
  var strUser = getYear.options[getYear.selectedIndex].value;
  var getJSON = document.getElementById("json-input").innerHTML;

  data = JSON.parse(getJSON);
  var year = strUser;

  let filterDataUtil = data.filter(function(dataItem) {
    return dataItem.birthday.split("/")[2] === strUser;
  });
}
```

```html
 <select id="js-year-selected" onchange="getYear()" class="js-year-input">
                <option value="2020">2020</option>
                <option value="2019" >2019</option>
                <option value="2018">2018</option>
                <option value="2017">2017</option>
                <option value="2016" >2016</option>
                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                <option value="2014">2014</option>
</select>

<textarea class="app__txt js-json" id="json-input" placeholder="Paste the json here.">[
    {
      "name": "Tyrion Lannister",
      "birthday": "12/02/2020"
    }, {
      "name": "Cersei Lannister",
      "birthday": "11/30/1975"
    }, {
      "name": "Daenerys Targaryen",
      "birthday": "11/24/1991"
    }, {
      "name": "Arya Stark",
      "birthday": "11/25/2020"
    }, {
      "name": "Jon Snow",
      "birthday": "12/03/1989"
    }, {
      "name": "Sansa Stark",
      "birthday": "08/15/1992"
    }, {
      "name": "Jorah Mormont",
      "birthday": "12/16/1968"
    }
]</textarea>
```

Comment: This part `dataItem.birthday.split("/")[2] === strUser` is sufficient, what is the following part for? `?  dataItem : ''`

Comment: Thanks @Thomas i have rectify my solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the two strings:

```
function getYear() {
  var getYear = document.getElementById("js-year-selected");
  var strUser = getYear.options[getYear.selectedIndex].value;
  var getJSON = document.getElementById("json-input").innerHTML;

  data = JSON.parse(getJSON);
  var year = strUser;
  console.log(year);

  let filterDataUtil = data.filter(function(dataItem) {
    if(dataItem.birthday.split("/")[2] === strUser){
      return dataItem;
    };
  });
  console.log(filterDataUtil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get Array then you can do following as mentioned below

```
let filterDataUtil = data.filter(function(dataItem) {
    return dataItem.birthday.split("/")[2] == strUser;
  });
console.log(filterDataUtil);
```

If you want to get Object only then you can do following as mentioned below

```
let filterDataUtil = data.find(dataItem => dataItem.birthday.split("/")[2] == strUser);
console.log(filterDataUtil);
```